# Join two Ruby hashes by keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes that look like this:

```
h1 = {key1: 'Roses are', key2: 'Violets are'}
h2 = {key1: 'Red', key2: 'Blue'}
```

I would like to join them by keys so that I get a hash like this:

```
result = {'Roses are' => 'Red', 'Violets are' => 'Blue'}
```

I have some code that does the trick:

```
result = {}
h1.each { |key, value| result[value] = h2[key] }
```

I wonder if there is a method in the standard lib to do this or whether this can be done with less code.

Comment: Less code? This is only 2 lines. If you really need, you can reduce it to one line using each_with_object, like: `result = h1.each_with_object({}) {|(key, value), h3| h3[value] = h2[key] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a 1:1 mapping, so [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) would work:

```
h1.map { |k, v| ... }
```

The values from `h1` become the new keys:

```
h1.map { |k, v| [v, ...] }
```

The corresponding values from `h2` become the new values:

```
h1.map { |k, v| [v, h2[k]] }
#=> [["Roses are", "Red"], ["Violets are", "Blue"]]
```

And [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h) converts that back into a hash:

```
h1.map { |k, v| [v, h2[k]] }.to_h
#=> {"Roses are"=>"Red", "Violets are"=>"Blue"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip the values:

```
h1 = {key1: 'Roses are', key2: 'Violets are'}
h2 = {key1: 'Red', key2: 'Blue'}
result = h1.values.zip(h2.values).to_h
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work when I change the order in 2nd hash, for example: h2 = {key2: 'Blue', key1: 'Red'}.

Comment: @msayen `h1.values.zip(h2.values_at(*h1.keys)).to_h` would fix that. [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) fetches the values for the given keys (in that order). Maybe you should change your example code accordingly so we don't make wrong assumptions.